# Reply after quiz is answered using a for loop and a replace

Tags: python

I have this code and I am having a little bit of trouble, because I need that after the person answered correctly, it should print the quiz with the blank (represented by ----1----, ----2----, etc...) filled by the answer, but I can't seem to get it to work, I have tried changing `def word_in_blanks()`, `def structure()` and `def fill_filled()`, I believe the problem is in `def fill_filled()`

here is [a link](https://repl.it/Gc9g/) to my code

Comment: The code is pretty complex, I've had a hard time tracing through it -- I'm not sure if it's related to your problem, but I noticed in the `def word_in_blanks(n):`, the `n` parameter doesn't get used in that method..

Comment: It is the remnant of a failed attempt, you can disregard it

Comment: Really? But you said you believe the problem is in `def fill_filled()` which uses `word_in_blanks(n)`..

Comment: So, what precisely is your problem? :)

Comment: @Todor The problem is the output `----1----, ----2----`, etc. should get replaced by the matching inputs. So when the user inputs the correct answer to complete the sentence, it fills that answer into the appropriate blank in answer. So, for level `easy`, the output should replace each `----1----`, `----2----`, `----3----`, `----4----` with each of `["input", "output", ".py", "return" ]`. But it doesn't yet, the output still contains the numbers when given correct input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the new [code](https://repl.it/Gigo/0), which works perfectly now.

I had to make some changes to it because some of it was too big.

anyway thanks for the attempts to help me!